Is there any way to get the attribute of the xpath whose index value keeps on changing when the user traverse from one page to another
I am using appium  for automating hybrid app and I switched my context to web view to use the attributes to find the x path. In my application when user traverse from one page to another page the index value of the attribute for Eg, in my first login the xpath is //[@id=createAccount] and when I go to the next page, then I came back to the login page the xpath is changed to (//[@id=createAccount])[2]. How can I solve this issue.
I am trying to use the id attribute of the application that is present in the web view , in native view, is it possible to use the web view attributes in native view


Id should be unique, if you are seeing multiple id with same name open defect with dev to sort this. 2) Try to reinitialize the element and see if works.

